# Ordering data.frames elegantly by factor

Tags: functional-programming, r

I have a mock_Data:

```
structure(list(Sample = structure(c(29L, 31L, 21L, 25L, 15L, 
17L, 13L, 27L, 23L), .Label = c("109d0", "109d2", "116d0", "116d2", 
"125d0", "125d2", "136d0", "136d2", "138d0", "138d2", "141d0", 
"141d2", "144d0", "144d2", "18d0", "18d2", "28d0", "28d2", "30d0", 
"30d2", "39d0", "39d2", "4d0", "4d2", "70d0", "70d2", "73d0", 
"73d2", "82d0", "82d2", "83d0", "83d2"), class = "factor"), Clinical = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("low faecal Salmonella shedding", 
"persistent faecal Salmonella shedding"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Sample", 
"Clinical"), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

And I need to reorder it so that the rows with the same Clinical factor are together.

So far I generated this function :

```
reorder_by_factor <- function(data, factor){
  # Function to get the indices of an unamed rows 
  flev <- levels(factor)
  ac <- function(data, factor, x){
    # Extract rownames
    rownames(data)[with(data, factor == x)]
  }
  ap <- sapply(flev, ac, data = data, factor = factor )
  unlist(ap)
}
```

that outputs the index of each factor ordered, and I can use it as `mock_Data[reorder_by_factor(mock_Data, mock_Data$Clinical),]`

I would like to be able to use it like lm with just `reorder_by_factor(mock_Data, Clinical)` and if possible make it more elegant and general, so it could take several factors and reorder them one, after the other. Also I would like to know which code would broke the function (aside from a data.frame with rownames)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the task you are attempting to accomplish (obtain indices to reorder a data frame by several factors, one after another) is already handled well by the built-in `order` function. Let's consider your sample data:

```
order(mock_Data$Clinical)
# [1] 1 3 5 7 8 2 4 6 9
```

As you can see, `order` is returning row numbers instead of row names; this yields an identical reordered data frame:

```
identical(mock_Data[reorder_by_factor(mock_Data, mock_Data$Clinical),],
          mock_Data[order(mock_Data$Clinical),])
# [1] TRUE
```

There are several other advantages of using the built-in `order` function:

- It already smoothly handles reordering by multiple factors, one after another
- It can reorder by a mix of factor and numeric variables
- It is already implemented and distributed with base R, so you don't need to develop and test your own version of this function

Another advantage is that the built-in `order` function is more efficient than your implementation. Let's see on a resampled version of your dataset with 1 million rows:

```
set.seed(144)
big.dat <- mock_Data[sample(seq_len(nrow(mock_Data)), 1e6, replace=T),]
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(reorder_by_factor(big.dat, big.dat$Clinical), order(big.dat$Clinical))
# Unit: milliseconds
#                                          expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq       max neval
#  reorder_by_factor(big.dat, big.dat$Clinical) 562.2527 744.4318 939.0831 898.6288 1054.0008 1678.1246   100
#                       order(big.dat$Clinical) 149.4750 153.2963 199.8178 160.5452  225.9082  459.5558   100
```

The built-in function runs about 5x faster.

Comment: Great!  I was reinventing de wheel. It was so obvious I didn't thought about it